# Opening LibreOffice Draw file from FTP (curlftpfs) fails

Tags: curlftpfs

I am using curlftpfs to map a folder:

```
mkdir ~/ftp_docs;
curlftpfs -o "user=myusername:mypassword" myftpserver.co.uk ~/ftp_docs/
```

here I can see ftp_docs and access the directory as any other on the system.

When I try to open a draw document by doing:

```
libreoffice --draw EveningChecklist.odg
```

I get a dialog showing:

> General input/output error while accessing /path/to/file.odg.

Only other changes I have made to the system is installing `at-spi2-core` which seemed recommended.

Can anyone advise?

**EDIT:** just a bit more information.   The same thing happens when using `gio mount` to mount the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution to this issue:

> Several GUI application (gedit, leafpad,...) use open(O_RDWR) + seek
>   mode for saving files  which cannot be supported by the FTP protocol.
>   Therefore saving files might throw an error. Hopefully future kernels
>   will provide special errno's to make it easier to  deal with less
>   capable file-systems.

Which is what https://github.com/JackSlateur/curlftpfs says.

The best solution is perhaps to just use LibreOffice's inbuilt File → Open Remote... functionality.